# Touch to continue (coroutine) in unity

Tags: unity, c#

When the object gets destroyed in my game, I want a `touch to continue` function after a delay. This is what I tried.

this is the `SceneManager` class which is attached to the `Main Camera`

```
 public bool ttc;
 public void NextLevel()
{
    StartCoroutine(Delay());
}
IEnumerator Delay()
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    print("touch to continue");
    ttc = true;}
```

My Object class:

```
   void OnDestroy()
  {
   Camera.main.GetComponent<SceneManager>().NextLevel();
    if (Camera.main.GetComponent<SceneManager>().ttc == true)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("TheGame2");
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
IEnumerator Delay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    print("touch to continue");
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("TheGame2");
        }
    }
```

*side note: I will change the 'KeyCode.V' to a mouse button later*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
IEnumerator Delay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    print("touch to continue");
    var pressed = false;
    while(!pressed){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            pressed = true;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
    Application.LoadLevel("TheGame2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated you will add a mouse button, I'll add that code here as well.

You would need to attach this to your scene manager

```
public bool IsDestroyed = false;
public bool ActivateGUI = false;

IEnumerator Delay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    ActivateGUI = true;
}

void OnGUI() //Button related stuff
{
    if (ActivateGUI)
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width - 10 - 100, Screen.height - 10 - 50, 100, 50), "Press Here"))
            Debug.Log("This repalces the press V code");
}


void Update()
{
    if (IsDestroyed)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Delay());
    }
}
```

The Update funtion is checking every frame if you object is detroyed. The OnGUI stuff is what draw the button.

Your OnDestroy funtion shoul be something similar to this

```
void OnDestroy()
{
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("GameManager");
    GameManager gm = go.GetComponent<GameManager>();
    gm.IsDestroyed = true;

    Destroy(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Object destroid");
}
```

I have read on the Unity forums that the GameObject.Find it is a really slow funtion, so caution is advised.

Hope this helps.